# React (Redux): Check if action has already been executed (Server Side rendering)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to accomplish the following:

My architecture currently executes server-side rendering on the initial request and resolves all promises to fill up the store with data before it returns to the client.

Now that works perfectly, the client receives a filled store and view. But it triggers the action once more (redundantly)

My ideal scenario would be that the serverside rendering adds a property to the result: "resolved: true" so you know the initial request came from the server and you can drop the redundant action, setting the property to false and returning that state instead via a middleware.

Currently I add the property:

```
{
resolved: true,
data: […]
}
```

My middleware would then need to check if the story currently has the data for this action and if so not execute the action again and set resolved to false, so the next time you come to this route it would reload the async data.

```
 return (store) => (next) => (action) => {
 // check if action data is already on store 
 // check if resolved property is true?
 return next(action);
 }
```

I was thinking of using a redux middleware. However I cannot know for certain what the returned data of my action will be mapped to on the store, since the reducer is in charge of this.

However I don't believe the middleware technique will work.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it inside your middleware you can use the store parameter like below, but I suggest checking inside an action creator.

```
return store => next => action => {
    state = store.getState(); // current state

    if (state.resolved) {
        return next(action);
    }

    // do loading
    next(action);
};
```

I strongly suggest taking a look at the Redux [real-world](https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) example; specifically the [middleware api](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js#L78-L123) and the [action creators](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/actions/index.js). You'll see in the action creators he does some rudimentary state checking before fetching.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. But I'm pretty sure that in the real-world example he doesn't account for the server already initializing the store. I looked at the code and it seems that it would also execute the action twice, once on the backend before render and again when rendered on the screen. I think checking inside the action creator is also a better approach. However I would need to keep a history of actions on the backend and pass them to the frontend which is not ideal?

Comment: If the store is initialized on the server, why aren't you sending that state to the client? You can do all the same dispatching, etc in between createStore() and render() on the server. When your app loads you should have the same state in your store. Therefore, when an action creator is called, getState() should use the state sent from the server and not be starting with an empty blank slate.

Comment: I did send the state to the client, the tricky part was telling the client not to reload on initial render, how we solved it was instead of sending the entire store over to the client. We wrote a middleware that logs the actions and sent the actions over to the client. Rebuilt the store based on those actions on the client. then added flags hasBeenExecuted and forceCheck to the action creator via thunk. We also added a forceExecute flag to an action. We set forceCheck to true and after the render function to false. It's a workaround to force the client to not rerender the initial serverload

Comment: Interesting... If it works, it works. I currently just call all my initial actions on the server and then send `store.getState()` to the client after all async actions have dispatched. What stack are you guys using?

Comment: We're using:  
Redux, React, Webpack, React Router, Node  

I'm actually writing an article about it, and how to tackle serverside rendering with this isormorphic stack. I'll send you the link when I'm done if you're interested?

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look at it. I'm actually doing the same thing, but I don't use Webpack in mine. I've been using NPM + Browserify, but without hot-loading.

Comment: I would totally look into webpack, it was a major performance win for us!